# Why am I getting a unexpected type, variable required error? even though I am using a variable

Tags: java, variables, primes, biginteger, compareto

```
List <BigInteger> valaArr = new ArrayList <BigInteger>();
        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number to test for prime: ");
        BigInteger n = value.nextBigInteger();

        for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(1); i.compareTo(n) = -1; i = i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))
        {
            valaArr.add(i);
        }
```

Apparently my i.compareTo(n) is giving me a unexpected type, variable required value found. Any idea why is it happening even though my i and n are variables?

Comment: you can't do this  i.compareTo(n) = -1 .. before = it must be a variable

Comment: Oh yea I just figured that out too! thanks

Comment: you required == for compare to i.compareTo(n) == -1

Comment: Also, BigInteger.ONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution

```
for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(1); i.compareTo(n) <0; i = i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))
{
 valaArr.add(i);
}
```